# Could I flag a possible duplicate to a question asking for a proof when I had already asked about the correctness of mine?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, solution-verification

That is, I asked before to check the correctness of my proof of that statement, and the correctness has been confirmed. Could I now flag a question asking for the proof of it as "possible duplicate" of my question?

Comment: Which question appeared for first, your proof-checking question or the proof-hunting question?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: My proof-checking. Maybe I know what you meant, it's about time precedence? But wouldn't it be strange to provide a question as an answer?

Comment: Because it would be "This question already has a answer" to "This question already has a ... question".

Comment: Some past discussions about this topic: [Closing as a duplicate if the post contains OP's own proof/solution](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12864) (and perhaps some of the [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/12864)) and [Proof-verification and duplicates.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11042)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your proof is *the* natural and generally accepted way to prove a certain statement, and it's hard to come up with alternative proofs, I'd say that's it's safe to close it as a duplicate.

If this is not the case, e.g. when your questions is asking to verify a proof that there are an infinite number of primes, it's certainly *not* appropriate to close it as a duplicate.