# Merging questions with multiple duplicates (not a duplicate)

Tags: discussion, support, exact-duplicates, merging

21 days ago from August 15, I asked my first question which looked like

$ a_1=1 ,\space a_{n+1}=a_n+\dfrac{1}{a_n} $

The question was marked as a duplicate by me undisputedly. But as being observant about the site content, I came to know that there are atleast 5-10 possible duplicates to this specific question on this site. Some of which contain really good answers (including one of mine [which can be found here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767681/if-a-1-1-and-for-n1-a-n-a-n-1-frac1a-n-1-then-a-246-lie)).

To make a request, can all of those questions be merged into a single question retaining all available information?

I read that this is supposed to be possible for a moderator [(here)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/20/linking-duplicate-questions/) on the parent site.

As a sidenote:

Can we create a thread on meta where we can compile questions which have large number of duplicates so that it's easier for the mod who volunteers to take up the task **Mission declutter x.y**?

I found a similar feature request [Describing how to set a heirarchy of duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29485/a-hierarchy-of-duplicates-which-questions-generalise-other-questions) but mine is a version which can be implemented with available tools and community effort.

Comment: Sometimes 2 questions appear to be duplicates when they are subtly different. If questions like this were merged, there would bound to be mistakes, and useful answers plus useful variations of a question could be deleted in the process. (1 of 3)

Comment: Currently, the highest voted question/answer will appear first in the search bar, which provides most people with an adequate answer that is neither too long or too short. If questions were merged, then the result would likely be significantly longer, and could appear cluttered. (2 of 3)

Comment: In short, the system works well enough as it is, and there are possible disadvantages with merging questions, so why change it? (3 of 3)

Comment: @user400188 The variations part is quite agreeable....but the thing is, if the questions are merged, we will have a single thread with all possible variations asked on the forum + people won't be discouraged to answer [duplicate] posts (with the variations you mentioned). Keeping a [duplicate] tags restricts a user to even attempt to answer an associated variation. This has happened not only on Math SE, but Chem/and mother meta as well. But, it's easier to solve the problem for Math SE because we can classify problems better

Comment: If we have a single thread with all possible variations of a question, then that thread would be infinitely long.

Comment: @user400188 The said is a possible loop hole because in time people might add more such variations but for that we might restrict to domain for admission into that post. Also, at the moment, if we consider that the question is about the sequence and series problem (here in my thread), the possible variations would only be 1. the closed form 2. the approximations ..... there maybe 3. a general case where $a_1≠1$ but would there be more than 3??.... if not(1/2)

Comment: I propose a Master thread to be created, all available variations be added and all answers merged accordingly, in that way authors will not loose their answers and the questions would be perfectly adiabetic (2/2)

Comment: You could have a sequence and series problem that has been solved by your professor, but you do not understand their proof, so you post it here asking for clarification along with your attempt to understand it. Since there are infinitely many ways to prove the same thing, we can expect a lot more than $3$ variations of sequence and series questions.

Comment: @user400188 but the question would still be marked a duplicate... is there a way to protect users from that? and then in the case of a [solution-verification] we might not merge it if it doesn't resemble the conformation. BUT. we can have a community edit to update variations of such answers in a single post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111815/discussion-between-user400188-and-anindya-prithvi).