# Solution verification questions and duplicates: proposal for discussion

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, solution-verification

When a user posts a (solution-verification) question on a problem (often a standard problem), I tend to not vote to close as a duplicate, since the user is asking for feedback on their particular solutions.

(Related: [this old meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11042/proof-verification-and-duplicates) )

In the recent weeks, there were two exception on my standard behavior: one was a question in which, after feedback was given, another user posted a *de nuovo* answer. After that, I closed the question as a duplicate using the golden-hammer.

The second was a now-deleted question in which the poster asked for hints for a standard problem (that a semigroup with a right identity and right inverses is a group). I closed as a duplicate, and the poster added an argument for half the problem, tagged as (solution-verification). Another golden-badge user re-opened. But the original poster was still asking for answers to the other half. When I pointed out it was still a duplicate, the user claimed that it was not *identical* to the previous question, and so could not possibly be a duplicate (as they were only asking about half the problem, not the whole thing). I said that was not the standard, but did not vote to close. The user deleted the post shortly thereafter.

I would like to make the following general policy proposal for (solution-verification) posts:

1. There should be no immediate votes to close a (solution-verification) post as a duplicate, to allow for suitable feedback.
2. After a suitable period (two days? three days? some other period), and once feedback has been given, it would be appropriate to vote to close these posts as duplicates.

(In fact, perhaps not only "appropriate", but "desirable"?)

3. If the solution provided is sufficiently different/of interest, encourage the poster to submit it as an answer to the duplicate question. Otherwise, just closing is appropriate.

**Reasoning:** I understand not voting to close (solution-verification) posts as an initial matter, so that users will not be turned away before sufficient feedback is given.

But we don't want multiple posts open on the exact same subject, and also when a lot of them will contain only small variations of standard arguments. Hence, the proposal to wait, but eventually close these posts once they have served their purpose.

---

To highlight/clarify:

What I'm hoping for is consensus that these questions, when they contain correct or nigh-correct answers, be "eventually" closed as duplicates. The precise meaning of "eventually" is perhaps where discussion might be warranted. I'm envisioning it as "not immediately", to (i) encourage/reward the effort; (ii) increase likelihood of engagement; (iii) give the poster the direct feedback they seek. Even a "closed as a duplicate" done pointing to an identical or near-identical argument is likely to be perceived as criticism rather than endorsement/encouragement.

Comment: To me, it's at least partially a function of the quality of the proposed answer.  In some (many?) cases, the proposed solution is so vague that little is served by trying to patch it up.  In those cases, closing the thing as a duplicate seems (to me) to make sense.

Comment: @lulu: I'm actually advocating for (eventual) closure. "Suitable period" may be an elastic standard depending on the quality of the proposal, of course. I guess I'm trying to see if there is consensus about a general site policy for them.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am suggesting.  A truly incoherent or irrelevant solution might be disregarded in favor of a "duplicate" which addressed the underlying question. On the other hand, a solid attempt might lead to a useful discussion.  Informally, though, it seems to me that the first case dominates.

Comment: Just looked at a few of the recent posts with this tag.  I guess part of my reaction is that people often misuse the tag.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284161/how-can-you-simplify-factorials-while-multiplying-them) for instance.  There is no solution provided, nothing to verify.  (And the claim is obviously false, but that's a separate problem)

Comment: @lulu Mis-tags should be re-tagged, of course. And incoherence can be voted to close. What about reasonable efforts? That's the ones that I'm mainly concern about. I don't want to golden-hammer them too soon, but I don't think it makes sense to just let them be indefinitely.

Comment: I will put forward---again---that I think that the best way to deal with unclear questions (including [tag:solution-verification] questions) is to close them, then give the asker time to correct the problems before folk can provide a large number of irrelevant answers.  Such questions *should* be closed as duplicates until and unless the asker can clearly articulate why their question is really novel.  Closure is not punitive---it is meant to either direct an asker to an answer, or to give them time to make improvements.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: And that I agree with; but how do we deal with *clear*, and let's say *correct* solution verification questions? This is what I am talking about, though the comment thread seems to have gone into what to do with those that are mislabeled or unclear while claiming solution verification. I know I brought up one such case, and I may have muddied the waters; it was more along the lines of why I decided to bring this up.

Comment: @XanderHenderson E.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283110/proof-that-sqrt2-is-not-a-rational-number). Perfectly fine and clear question, received adequate feedback, and does things that are *already done elsewhere*; certainly lots of posts on the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, and even one on the fact that [an $n$th root is either an integer or irrational using the same argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11872/is-nth-root-of-2-an-irrational-number/11875#11875). Shouldn't the first one be closed as a duplicate **now**?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Honestly, I am of the opinion that [tag:solution-verification] questions are a very poor fit for this site.  They tend to be very narrow, and of little long-term use to others, while cluttering the database.  I am of the opinion that the tag should be burninated.  However, my impression is that there is zero consensus about this in the community here, so I try to ignore the tag as much as possible.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin There are probably thousands of questions on this site about the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, and $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{7}$ and whatever else, all of which come down to three or four standard arguments.  The should probably all be closed as duplicates of one another.

Comment: @Xander, you really want to close **all** questions about irrationality of (say)  $\sqrt2$ as duplicates of each other? Close Question A as a duplicate of Question B, and B as a duplicate of A? By transitivity, you're suggesting closing a question as a duplicate of itself. That would certainly make it easier to declutter this website. Declutter it to the point of denuding it.

Comment: See also [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29119/11619).

Comment: [My views](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30083/11619), for what they are worth.

Comment: I am siding with Xander. In my opinion it would be best if we simply disallowed solution-verification and proof-verification questions altogether. The askers may honestly do a good job in searching the site, but the answerers just keep posting duplicate answers. Alternatively such answers could be brought under EOQS sanctions.

Comment: At the very least I move that answers to a solution-verification /proof-verification question MUST first and foremost discuss the attempt. Similar errors do recur, and finding duplicates is problematic. In a sense, a duplicate to a failed attempt would be another question where *a similar logical error is explained*. Possibly in a vastly different context.

Comment: Concerning 1.: it the poster gives a more or less correct attempt, isn't closing as duplicate the best feedback they can get? They get to see the same method used and posted here, and also they can see other method.

Comment: @ArcticChar That makes great sense. As an extension, what also makes sense is someone who makes a partial attempt on a question which is correct *thus far* and wants critique on it. Then, a duplicate question with a complete answer that contains that particular argument as part of its reasoning, would also make a duplicate candidate. My stance on this issue was similar to Arturo's earlier one, in that I wouldn't close SV questions as duplicates at all. If this policy is effected, we are in a position to at least attempt to move forward on this resolution.

Comment: This is an interesting proposal. On the one hand, I also agree that solution-verification and proof-verification are often of very little lasting value. On the other hand, I'm against a class of posts that are meant to be temporary.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Just wondering : what "feedback" are you referring to? I ask this since all kinds of feedback, bar an answer, can be provided in a closed question as well. It might be just the effect of closure (in the second question, a conversation on closure was followed by deletion) that may have influenced how (1) was framed. My trouble with this, and I want to know if you share the same is : are you okay allowing answers to such questions for a longer period? Delaying closure to wait for feedback will almost surely lead to this. If we're ok on this occurring, then I don't see a problem.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: I think that those who take the time to "show their work" should be at least mildly encouraged (as something adjacent to the new Community Standards on lack of context). Closing the question, I think, is perceived as dismissal ("Just go look here instead...") While comments can be posted after closure, I would expect them to have less of an appreciated impact. For generally correct answers, where you might just get "Yes, this works" or "Almost, but there's this detail here", I would advocate for providing that feedback, and after a suitable wait (even if just an hour), closing.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: For answers that have some fatal error that can re-occur, an actual answer addressing this would be suitable and closure may be discussed (but I would strongly discourage what happens sometimes, where you post explaining the error, and then you get into a back-and-forth where the poster tries to correct their argument by further editing the post).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Ultimately, I would hope for consensus that these questions need to be "eventually" closed as duplicates, with perhaps some allowance given to encourage those who are taking the time to post their coherent work by not doing so *immediately*, but only after they've gotten some engagement.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin While I wish the perception around closure could change, so that we could close, converse, reopen/clarify and prepare for eventual deletion, I think the policy is progressive enough. I understand we want everybody to receive engagement, particularly if their posts are otherwise well written. It also seems that you are ok with answers such as "Yes , this works" and so on, while I'm more comfortable with such assertions appearing in the comments, but I think that's a minor difference. Thanks for your explanations, and +1 to your suggestion.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I'm *not* okay with posted answers that consist only of "yes, this works." In fact, I will flag such answers as being "not an answer", or comment saying so. I'm okay with the post receiving only *comments* saying that (and then would like the community to agree to close them afterwards).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ok, that makes it even clearer. I got the impression because you said " I would advocate for providing that feedback, and after a suitable wait (even if just an hour), closing" following the part I referred to, but I think I misunderstood the class of answers you were referring to. Then we are on the same page, probably on the same line as well.

Comment: I think Jyrki makes great points, but I also believe Arturo is posting a legitimate concern.,  I think they both capture the heart of the matter.  I think if folks stopped talking past each other a tad here, and actually listened to each other, we have the making of a well-reasoned compromise/solution that makes a heck of a lot of sense.  Thanks, @Arturo, and Jyrki for your level headedness in this discussion!

Comment: Since some of the comments are about answer to this type of questions, I will add a link to a previous discussion: [How to answer proof-verification questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20097)

Comment: I took a quick look at the most recent activity on solution-verification. I will concede that the situation is not as grim as I though it might, Many had no answers at all (probably due them not being elementary and relatively fresh). [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4283115/11619) was the first example of what I had in mind. A wall of text as a question. None of the answerers discussed it but rather posted their own solutions. This question was near the bottom of the first page of 50, so the frequency of such posts is apparently not too high.

Comment: (cont'd) May be when such a question attracts many answers it is of that type :-(

Comment: @Jyrki, I remember such situations, not as frequently now, where, as you mention, answerers offer different proofs or solutions, rather than giving feedback on the proposed solution, in which the purpose of asking  for "solution verification" is entirely lost.  It seems we are dealing with many interpretations of "solution verification" from askers who use the tag, and answerers who answer questions tagged as such.  I think Martin's link immediately above your post addresses the "answering" end of things.

Comment: I'm going to peek at the "solution-verification/proof-verification* tag description.  It might need to be pinned down.

Comment: The tag could use some expansion, but it seems never to justify alternative answers.

Comment: Concerning your edit: In the few times when I vote to close a "solution verification" question (since their approach are more or less correct), I never encounter any setback. The most recent time I left a comment like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236603/prove-limsup-n-to-inftya-nb-n-leq-limsup-n-to-inftya-n-limsup-n-to-in#comment8803799_4236603) and the OP close the post as duplicate. May be it is easier for me since I don't have the gold-hammer.

Comment: It feels like most of the time, if a user posts something of this form where the question has a solution and they're looking for verification, it's often too open ended for it to be on topic and really it ends up being little more than flame bait that wastes time, frays nerves and detracts from the purpose and reputation of the site at large, because it causes a duplicate/non-duplicate conflict.  We're on here to help each other solve problems and not to insult each other's intelligence.

Comment: @amWhy Maybe these tags need to be removed.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I respect your position, but at the same time I think you underestimate the potential for question closures and deletions to come across as punitive, even if the curation process isn't intended to be punitive in itself, and that's why I argue that the tags are perhaps, too blurry in scope and give users the wrong impression about what is allowed and what is not allowed on the site, particularly given the way the knowledge base has grown since the site was founded.

Comment: @JustKevin  I think it would be a good thing for the tag to be removed.  (proof-verification is considered a "synonym" of solution-verification, so selecting either will publish only solution-verification).  But, at least at first, such questions will likely continue, without that tag, if it is not available.  If the tag is burninated, we'd likely need to make it clear in a meta post, posted by a moderator, perhaps, with a custom comment included for users to initially past in response to questions asking for verification.

Comment: @JustKevin I also agree with you comment above the comment I just addressed. And also the comment just below the one I first addressed.    You seem like a natural fit for math.meta.se! :-)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Why do you think that if two different problems can be solved by the same argument, one should be closed as duplicate of the other? Granted in the "square root irrationality" case you have provided, the problem themselves are rather similar, but aren't very different problems which may be solved using the same argument as well?

Comment: My view is similar to [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34221/solution-verification-questions-and-duplicates-proposal-for-discussion#comment158183_34221) of @Xander. Most SV questions lack sufficent context, i.e. they don't say *precisely* where the doubt lies (and why). So usually the best choice is to quickly (gold) close as a dupe (lacking context closures are too slow to prevent floods of dupe answers). If OP clarifies then either we can refine dupe links (or answers) if need be, or else reopen the novel good (clarified) question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You say "Close Question A as a duplicate of Question B, and B as a duplicate of A?"  I am not sure how you got that idea, and this is impossible, anyway (the software prevents it).  Rather, I am in favor of producing canonical Q&A threads for FAQs---for example, the three questions which I have posted on the site are *all* about creating canonical duplicate targets for frequently asked questions.  I am in favor of either choosing an existing question as such a canonical target, or producing a canonical question for (e.g.) irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ questions.

Comment: @Divide1918 Mathematics is not about performing rote computations to solve specific problems.  It is about creating *reasoning* which allows one to solve *many* problems at once.  There is no reason to have questions about the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ and $\sqrt{7}$ and so on when there are one or two arguments which will answers *all* of those questions at the same time.

Comment: @XanderHenderson The point I was trying to raise is that, it's not always clear to a questioner that their question is inherently identical and may be solved in the exact same reasoning process as a pre-existing question. So they might get confused when e.g. their question got closed as dupe of some other question that they have absolutely no idea had anything to do with their original question

Comment: @Xander, thank you for clarifying your comment of 22 October.